# Trying to understand angular.copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand what angular.copy will do. I've seen one example in Angular js doc but not able to figure out why reset button is not working after filling all the text fields and clicking on save button. But it works when we click on reset button before clicking on Save.Can someone please explain.Thanks in advance

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></label><br />
    <label>Age:  <input type="number" ng-model="user.age" /></label><br />
    Gender: <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male</label>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female</label><br />
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
  </form>
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
angular.
  module('copyExample', []).
  controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.reset = function() {
      // Example with 1 argument
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      // Example with 2 arguments
      angular.copy(user, $scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
  }]);
```

Comment: pls see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.user` does not even exist before you click reset.

Comment: that was not the issue, at the end of the controller he calls `$scope.reset();` and eventually the `$scope.user` is instantiated. the issue was a typo over the copy function....

Answer (score 0):

> Angular `copy` method **only** allocate another instance of memory to from
>   `master` to `user`. And Will avoid reference issues if you don't want to change `user` without changing `master`;

reference [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

### You problem is in `$scope.user` instead of just `user`:

Working snippet bellow:

```
$scope.update = function(user) {
      // Example with 2 arguments
      angular.copy($scope.user, $scope.master);
    };
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q',
      function($scope, $q) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.reset = function() {
      // Example with 1 argument
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      // Example with 2 arguments
      angular.copy($scope.user, $scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();


      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></label><br />
    <label>Age:  <input type="number" ng-model="user.age" /></label><br />
    Gender: <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male</label>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female</label><br />
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
  </form>
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>

  </div>
</body>
```